# Understanding "order matters" on external .js files in html

Tags: javascript

EDIT:

Okay, gonna try to use as little code as possible to explain my problem.

I have a select dropdown menu that has a function changetext() tied to it. Whenever a value is selected in the dropdown menu, text inside a  tag is changed.

The script to the function is stored in an external js file and is placed at the bottom of my html file.

Inside the js file is something like this.

```
var selectormenu = document.getElementById("selector");
var spanTag = document.getElementById("texthere");

function changetext(){
    if(selectormenu.value == "one"){
        spanTag.innerHTML = "one";
    }
}
```

By using this js file, I get a TypeError in my browser console. However, if I place var selectormenu and spanTag inside the function, the script works.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. So `soandso !== Soandso`

Comment: It just means that `divid` doesn't exist on the page at the time it runs; that's why it's `null`. It's hard to tell why your div isn't on the page without seeing more context.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources (like your JavaScript files) to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] instead and put it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Since the question case sensitivity was fixed, I am adjusting my answer. You need the DOM element to already be created, because `document.getElementById` needs to have something to select. Then, your function needs to be named before the parentheses. Finally, you need to call the function, because it won't run unless it's called.

```
<div id="divid>Hello World!</div>
<script>
var soandso = document.getElementById("divid");

function statsChange() {
    soandso.innerHTML = "123";
} 
statsChange();
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm on my phone so auto capitalization is on. It's fixed now.

Comment: Do you have a link to the code like on jsfiddle or codepen or anything? The things I notice are 1) `onclick` is not a method in plain JS, you will have to use `addEventListener`, and 2) the event listener shouldn't need to be inside a function at all
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: But would the onclick cause the variable to me null as indicate by browser console? I would just like to point out that the code given in my OP is an example.

Comment: The main thing that would cause the variable to be null is if the element doesn't exist - you need in your html a `<div id="divid">Hello World!</div>`, because that is the element that you are trying to select. Your example works for me when all I add is a DOM element with an id of divid

Comment: I adjusted my answer again, hopefully this one will get you up and running :) And of course, the inside of the script tag in my example can be in a separate file.

Comment: Do you think it's because in my first js file my script is wrapped in a $(document).ready(function() {}) ;? And then the js (with the var and function) where I placed at just before the body tag is affected?

Comment: It's giving me a type error meaning that the Id I'm trying to get does not exist, which made me think maybe there is something wrong with the sequence of loading the codes.

Comment: It's hard to say from the code that's posted here, but yeah, the core problem is that the DIV that you are trying to select by id does not exist yet at the time the js is loaded.

Comment: Edited my original post. You can see the difference when variable is placed outside of the function.

Comment: Apparently, I should not post jsfiddle in my OP. Here is a jsfiddle that works. http://jsfiddle.net/mbhom8hb/ and then this one doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/a6qvzzkf/